# Just a theoretical question about the geometry and form of the Black Hole

Tags: black-holes, collision, event-horizon, neutron-stars

This is just something theoretical so please do not answer with a whole bunch of data but with a logical presumption about the next theoretical scenario.. There is a collision between a not so big BH (so the gravitational time dilation is evident only at the very proximity of the BH EH) and a not so easly deformable astrophysical object as a Neutron star... **1**) If the BH Event horizon is populated with matter and energy should this fact provoke a visible deformation of the infalling Neutron star (obviously we would see the part of the NS that is more distant from the BH EH so we can see it with no time dilation) and **2**) if this was not the case should we see the part of the incomming NS that is farther regarding the BH with no any squeezing deformation?

Comment: *"If the BH Event horizon is populated with matter and energy"* Do you mean that the BH has an accretion disk? Does the BH have a lot of spin?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are asking whether we can determine whether there is a firewall just beyond the event horizon of a black hole by dropping a rigid object into it, and seeing if the part still outside the black hole slows down when the front collides with the firewall.

The answer is no. There are no perfect 'rigid bodies' in relativity - the forces on one part of a solid body are transmitted to the rest of the body at around the speed of sound in the material, which is always less than the speed of light.

In particular, responses to a future impact cannot travel backwards in time, and across the event horizon the entire future light cone is tilted *inwards*, into the black hole. All the products and effects of any collision would be kept inside the future light cone, inside the hole.

The event horizon and everything inside it is in the *future* of every external observer, and cannot be seen from or affect anything outside the hole, in its past. We can only observe events in the past, on our backwards-pointing *past* light cone. So what we see when we look towards a black hole is its entire *past* history, the light of which has been trapped just outside the hole for eons, red-shifted into the appearance of blackness.

[I have seen it suggested](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_%28physics%29#Characteristics_and_detection) that the presence of a firewall might affect the 'ringing' oscillations of the horizon when some large mass falls in, producing 'echoes' after the event, due to [gravitational waves bouncing between the perturbed horizon and the firewall](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.00266.pdf). This is not an effect of the future collision on the part of the rigid body still outside the hole - this is an effect of the body's gravity on the shape of spacetime around the hole. They have looked for predicted effects in the gravitational waves given out by black hole mergers. But I don't know how plausible that is. It seems to me that causal effects cannot travel from the future into the past, and the same goes for gravitational disturbances. (We cannot use gravitational waves to signal faster than light, either.) Any differences due to a firewall *genuinely* inside the horizon would have to propagate inwards, I would think. But given that the event horizon of a black hole is a mathematical construct that can depend partly on future events, like masses yet to fall in, it may be that the firewall 'does not know' it is forming *outside* the horizon! I think it a dubious speculation, but this may be a line of research you might find worth exploring further.